# Not able to change attribute in $templateCache using an AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

This is my Directive :

```
module.directive('iconSwitcher', function() {

return {
    restrict : 'A',

    link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        var currentState = true;

        elem.on('click', function() {
            console.log('You clicked me!');

            if(currentState === true) {
                console.log('It is on!');
                angular.element(elem).removeAttr(attrs.src);
                angular.element(elem).attr(attrs.src, "../images/First.png");

            } else {
                console.log('It is off!');
                angular.element(elem).removeAttr(attrs.src);
                angular.element(elem).attr(attrs.src, "../images/Second.png");

            }

            currentState = !currentState

        });
    }
};
});
```

My aim is onClick I change the image source to another one. Normally it should work on html, But I don't know why it's not working when it comes to templateCache HTML.
It must be something related to Directives and templateCache in AngularJS but I am new in this field and I don't have enough experience I guess.

```
    $templateCache.put('timeline_cursor.tpl.html', '<div icon-switcher><img style=" margin-bottom:6px;cursor:pointer;" src="../images/First.png" "/></div>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems lie inside your `iconSwitcher` directives :

1. `jqLite` function `removeAttr` and `attr` does not recognize your attribute name - ie. `attrs.src` and it will `throw Error`. You must change your attribute into `src` :

   ```
   elem.removeAttr('src', 'your/image/path');
   elem.attr('src', your/image/path);
   ```
2. The position of your `iconSwitcher` directive inside your `$templateCache` and the way you call your element inside your `iconSwitcher` has conflict. Because in your `$templateCache` you put the `icon-switcher` attribute in the `div` instead in `img` tag, the `elem` inside your directive will be bound the the whole `div` inside `$templateCache` instead of `img`. You can work around this by either put the `iconSwicher` in the `img` tag or find `img` element by using `jqLite find` inside `link`:

   ```
   var img = elem.find('img');
   ```

   And change the `src` attribute of `img` instead of `elem`.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/dg5zzwgt/) for your reference.

Comment: +1 Thank you a lot, i Started changing my whole code because i didn't get an answer. Thanks it's working And I appreciate the explanation. I understand now how it is working. Thank you :)